# live highlight a word(s) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlighting

I want to live highlight words with jQuery. I use a live keyup event to trigger the highlighting, so that the highlighting changes upon entering words(using a input text field for this)

I have found a piece of code which works fine but this code doesn't works with the live keyup event, so it wraps the first letter and stops there.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input" name="input"/>
<div id="content-block"><p>lorem ip sum </p></div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
$('#input').live('keyup', function() {
    $('#input').trigger('highLight');
});

$('#input').bind('highLight', function() {
    var o = {words:$('input[name="input"]').val()};
    highlight("content-block",  o);
});

function highlight(id, options) {

    var o = {
                words: '',
                caseSensitive: false,
                wordsOnly: true,
                template: '$1<span class="highlight">$2</span>$3'
            }, 
        pattern;

    $.extend(true, o, options || {});

    if (o.words.length == 0) { return; }
    pattern = new RegExp('(>[^<.]*)(' + o.words + ')([^<.]*)', o.caseSensitive ? "" : "ig");

    $('#'+id).each(function() {

        var content = $(this).html();

        if (!content) return;
        $(this).html(content.replace(pattern, o.template));

    });

}
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer for a solution, not just an identification of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that after the first successful replace the pattern now has to also match the ending span tag that has been inserted after the first matched character.

The HTML looks like this after entering "l":

```
<p><span class="highlight">l</span>orem ip sum</p>
```

"lorem" will no longer match because of the span.

**Now with solution:**

Here is a fix that should get it doing what you want:

```
$('#' + id).each(function() {
    $('span.highlight',this).replaceWith($('span.highlight',this).text()); // Fix

    var content = $(this).html();

    if (!content) return;
    $(this).html(content.replace(pattern, o.template));
});
```

Assuming that you will only have a single highlight span, the line below removes the span and replaces it with the text that it contained. Then the replace happens as normal.

```
$('span.highlight',this).replaceWith($('span.highlight',this).text()
```

A working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanrolds/N4DCR/

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for multiple highlight in the same paragraph, as [pointed here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22280829/1420197) and reproduced [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N4DCR/148/) (search *ip*, only the last word is highlighted). Maybe a fix would be useful to the other users.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. However, if you duplicate the  <p>'s to the <div id='content-block'> in the fiddle, you'll see there is a bug in which highlighted characters are duplicated. Any chance for an update? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the global flag for your regular expression even if you are in case-sensitive mode. This is probably why only the first char gets replaced. Try using this:

```
pattern = new RegExp('(>[^<.]*)(' + o.words + ')([^<.]*)', (o.caseSensitive ? "" : "i") + "g");
```

Comment: still wraps the first letter, i see that my example code have been edited and missing some parts...

Comment: sorry about that, was formatting it for readability ... should be fixed soon.