# How to highlight words in a table with a filter?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, highlight

I want to create a table with a filter which highlights the keywords that has been searched while displaying the search results.

I like the answer of this question: [live highlight a word(s) with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064638/live-highlight-a-words-with-jquery) but I couldn't figure out how to implement it in my existing code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search...">
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
       <h1>Text</h1>
       <p><span class="red">Text</span></p>
       <p>Text</p>
    </td>
    <td><img src=".."></td>
  </tr>
  <td>
       <h1>Text</h1>
       <p><span class="red">Text</span></p>
       <p>Text</p>
    </td>
    <td><img src=".."></td>
</table>
```

Comment: So you have defined an objective and shown us some code but haven't identified what the specific problem is with that code or any errors it produces or what the code does or doesn't do specifically and where you are having specific problems.Would also help to provide enough sample data in the table to make the whole thing runnable as in [mcve]

Comment: Note you can probably easily find highlighting scripts readily available on the web

Comment: It looks like you are only looking in the first <td> for your word match, if your word happens to be in the other td tags in the row, it won't match those.  If you want to find words in the other td tags, you will have to add a nested loop to run across those.

Answer (score 0):

Try mark.js (https://markjs.io/):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/7.0.0/mark.min.js'> 
</script>
```

and

```
function myFunction(txelem, destid) {

   var instance = new Mark(document.querySelector('#' + destid));
   instance.unmark({
      done: function() {
         instance.mark(txelem.value, {
             caseSensitive: false
         });
     }
  });

  return;
}
```

A running example can be found on https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/atmg9peq/11/

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try this

```js
function createTagAndAppendTo(tag, txt, elem){
  let customTag = document.createElement(tag);
  customTag.textContent = txt;
  elem.append(customTag);
}

function myFunction(evt) {
  // Declare variables
  let input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  let displayTr = [];
  filter = evt.value;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  let regExp = new RegExp(filter);
  if (!filter) {
    for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      tr[i].style.display = '';
    }
    return;
  }

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    let trStyle = tr[i].style.display;
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (let j = 0; j < td.length; j++) {

        txtValue = td[j].textContent;

        let count = (txtValue.match(regExp) || []).length;
        displayTr[i] = displayTr[i] ? displayTr[i] : count;
        if (count !== 0) {
          
          td[j].innerText = '';
          let strArray = txtValue.split(filter);
          let loopLength = strArray.length - 1;

          for (let i = 0; i < loopLength; i++) {
            createTagAndAppendTo('span', strArray[i], td[j]);
            createTagAndAppendTo('mark', filter, td[j]);
          }
          createTagAndAppendTo('span', strArray[loopLength], td[j]);
          
        } else {
          let tdStr = td[j].textContent;
          td[j].innerText = '';
          td[j].textContent = tdStr;
          
        }
      }
    
    if(displayTr[i] !== 0) {
      tr[i].style.display = '';
    } else {
       tr[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction(this)" placeholder="Search...">
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>success</td>
    <td>Substring</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that I would like to have more html tags in between the td tags. In this case if I use your code it messes up the whole structure of my td...

Comment: Could you please provide the structure of the `html` tags. Also, be very specific about your requirements.

Comment: ok. Thanks.
Now, you want to check the txt in every `html` tags and highlight the searched text?

Comment: Exactly, without destroying the structure of the html

Comment: @Jay did you solve your issue, or is it still there ?

Comment: It's still there

Comment: Whilst the code does still lose html inside the TD tags, I've posted a jsfiddle of the code for better visualisation: https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/dtkq8L3v/3/